# How to group results with Slick

Tags: scala, slick

Let's say I have those two models:

```
case class Department(id: Long, title: String)
case class Program(id: Long, departmentId: Long, title: String)
```

And two `TableQuery`, `departments` and `programs`, based on `Table` mapped to those case classes respectively.

I would like to make a query returning a `Seq[(Department, Seq[Program])]`, where I have a list of departments with their corresponding programs.

I started like this:

```
val query = 
  (departments join programs on ((d, p) => d.id === p.departmentId))
    .groupBy {...}
```

But what ever I put in the group by clause just doesn't make sense.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```scala
val query = departments.join(programs).on(_.id === _.departmentId)
        .result
        .map(_.groupBy(_._1.id))

db.run(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

@osehyum, thanks for your answer. Your query is returning this:

```
Map[Long, Seq[(Department, Program)]]
```

The `Long` here is for the Department Id.

I managed to turn it with this:

```
val query = departments.joinLeft(programs).on(_.id === _.departmentId).result
    .map(_.groupBy(_._1).toSeq)
    .map(items => items.map { case (dep, rows) =>
      (dep, rows.map(_._2).filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get))
    })
```

Note that I used `joinLeft` this time, so `Program` became `Option[Program]`, so I had to `filter` and `map`. It is tested.

Comment: I hope there is no additional performance impact due to the fact that I group by the whole row, rather than the Id. Slick should be using the Id and then aggregating by row instead of Id.